# using series of animations on different images one after another

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I need to do series of animation on 4 different images. The images are arranged in sequence. It will begin with movement of first image and when it stops the second one will move and similarly others will follow. Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Pankaj

**Answer**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                 animations:^{ 
                     ballon1.center = CGPointMake(260, 50);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                                      animations:^{ 
                                          ballon2.center = CGPointMake(260, 140);
                                      } 
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                                               animations:^{ 
                                                                   ballon3.center = CGPointMake(260, 230);
                                                               } 
                                                               completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                                   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                                                                    animations:^{ 
                                                                                        ballon4.center = CGPointMake(260, 320);
                                                                                    } 
                                                                                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                                                        ;
                                                                                    }];
                                                               }];

                                          }
                                      ];

                 }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    self.image1.frame = [self frameForImage1];
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        self.image2.frame = [self frameForImage2];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
       // etc. for images 3 and 4
    }];
}];
```

Or if you'd rather do your animations using `beginAnimations:context:` and `commitAnimation`, then you can use `setAnimationDelegate:` and `setAnimationDidStopSelector:` to chain together a series of selectors to animate each image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for image animation with time count...If so you can use this

```
UIImageView *animView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 855, 768, 92)];
animView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"01.jpg"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"02.jpg"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"03.jpg"],nil];



// all frames will execute in 1.5 seconds 
animView.animationDuration = 7;

// repeat the annimation forever
animView.animationRepeatCount = 0;

// start animating
[animView startAnimating];

// add the animation view to the main window 
[webView addSubview:animView];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: no I am not asking for this. I have 4 different images and I have to move them one after another. These images will be different from each other and will take different place. Every images must move after the image prior to it have stopped